# android sd card

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I'm trying to run the Android emulator, and I can't get it to recognize the SD Card.

I've gone through all the usual setup steps–I've made sure my app has the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in its manifest, I've made sure my avd has SD card support enabled (`hw.sdCard = yes`), I've made sure I specified an SD Card in the AVD setup. When I run the app, it fails to create any new files or directories, and when I call `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` to check if the SD Card is mounted, it always returns `removed`.

I've run other, known-good projects to see if I get the same error, and I've had other people try to run the code to see if they can get it to work. All the other projects have the same problem, and other people who have run the code have gotten it to work.

I am running OS X 10.8.2 on a Retina Macbook Pro, Eclipse Juno release, and using the Android SDK preview release 21rc4.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

ADDENDUM: Here is the text of the config.ini file for the avd in question:

```
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.lcd.density=240
sdcard.size=1024M
skin.name=WVGA800
skin.path=platforms/android-16/skins/WVGA800
hw.cpu.arch=arm
abi.type=armeabi-v7a
hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8
vm.heapSize=48
hw.ramSize=512
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a/
```

Comment: Can you post the config.ini of your avd?  It resides in ~/.android/avds/<avdname>.avd/config.ini

Comment: Posted the text of that file.

Comment: In that same directory you should have a sdcard.img, and it should be 1073741824 bytes.  If you run file on it: file ~/.android/avd/sdcardtest.avd/sdcard.img, you should get something like this:Users/pete/.android/avd/sdcardtest.avd/sdcard.img: x86 boot sector, code offset 0x5a, OEM-ID "MSWIN4.1", sectors/cluster 4, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors 2097152 (volumes > 32 MB) , FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 4088, reserved3 0x800000, serial number 0x180b3619, label: "     SDCARD"

Comment: Everything matches, except for the serial number (obviously).

Comment: Have you checked logcat for anything related to the sdcard?

Comment: 09-25 17:55:31.963: D/MountService(371): got storage path: /mnt/sdcard description: USB storage primary: true removable: false emulated: false mtpReserve: 0 allowMassStorage: false maxFileSize: 0
09-25 17:55:32.043: D/MountService(371): volume state changed for /mnt/sdcard (null -> removed)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the sdcard.img file exists, and is the correct size, and is writeable by your login.  If that doesn't work, you can try re-creating it with the following command:

```
mksdcard 1024M sdcard.img
```

Comment: It does exist, and is writable.